# Im trying to input a line in the console and it seeing if it equals the string using this code:

Tags: java, eclipse, console

This is my code to see if the the console input is equal to the String.

```
boolean Cool1 = ask("rlrlrl");


public boolean ask(String a) {
    String b = scan.nextLine();
    out("You put: " + b);
    if (b == a) {
    System.out.println("Good!");
    return true;
    } else {
    System.out.println("Ugly");
    return false;
    }
}
```

This always returns false. Why?

Comment: print a inside the function and see if a is really equal to b

Comment: String comparison works better with a.equals(b) than a == b (which checks reference, not equality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use .equals method to compare string content. ==  will check object's reference only.